# How to find time transformation given certain coordinate transformations?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems

Let’s say that you’re given a coordinate transformation (say, from Cartesian to spherical) in General Relativity, how do you find the time coordinate transformation? Or is there no way of knowing this?

Comment: Time always transforms differently than the spatial coordinates as far as I know. Look up a Lorentz transformation for instance. You always have some metric tensor components $g_{ij}$ that desribes how the coordinates change, the specific case of course if specified by this metric.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is inconsistent with the geometric description of spacetime. In special and general relativity what has physical meaning is the spacetime interval $ds$ given by:
$ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$
where:
$g_{\mu \nu}$ metric tensor
$x^\mu$ coordinate

A coordinate change from $x^\mu$ to $x^{\mu '}$ refers to all of the coordinates, that is:
$dx^{\mu '} = (\partial x^{\mu '} / \partial x^\mu) dx^\mu$

The time coordinate is unrelated to the spatial coordinates only in Newtonian physics, but SR (special relativity) superseded it in the description of reality.

Comment: I am not really sure why you consider this an "answer". You haven’t really answered anything.

Comment: If you are given a coordinate transformation, the time transformation should be included as time is a coordinate as well. If not, that means time is unrelated to the other coordinates, but that is Newtonian physics, not SR or GR.

Comment: @Michele_Grosso okay in GR how do you find the time transformation?

Comment: @Y2H  what Michele Grosso is trying to say, I guess, is that there is no unique time transformation. So you can't calculate the time transformation given the spatial one if you are not trying to preserve something further.

Comment: Thank you @AlejandroMenaya. That’s what I needed to know. Any reference for this?